# Remainder operator in C# perform different than MOD in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have found a strange situation converting a piece of code from C# to VB.NET, the code is a small class that convert from base 10 to base 36 and vice versa.

the key point is this function :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A Base36 De- and Encoder
    /// </summary>
    public static class Base36
    {
        private const string CharList = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        /// <summary>
        /// Encode the given number into a Base36 string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static String Encode(long input)
        {
            if (input < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", input, "input cannot be negative");

            char[] clistarr = CharList.ToCharArray();
            var result = new Stack<char>();
            while (input != 0)
            {
                result.Push(clistarr[input % 36]);
                input /= 36;
            }
            return new string(result.ToArray());
        }
```

that converted in VB.NET should result in :

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class Base36
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Private Const CharList As String = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Encode the given number into a Base36 string
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="input"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Shared Function Encode(input As Int64) As String
        If input < 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", input, "input cannot be negative")
        End If

        Dim clistarr As Char() = CharList.ToCharArray()
        Dim result = New Stack(Of Char)()
        While input <> 0
            result.Push(clistarr(input Mod 36))
            input /= 36
        End While
        Return New String(result.ToArray())
    End Function
```

The problem is that the modulo operator in VB.NET perform differently that the % remainder operator in C#, in fact if you call the encode method in C# :

```
        long l = 13072113072399; 
        string result = Base36.Encode(l);   //Result is : 4mt8um0b3
```

while calling the method in C# :

```
    Dim l As Int64 = 13072113072399
    Dim result As String = Base36.Encode(l) //Result is : 5nujsu3ar
```

The responsible of the difference is the different result that the modulo operator return in some situations, why ?

What is the equivalent of the % remainder operator in VB.NET ?

Comment: If you think the operator is giving you different results, then write up a small self-contained example that demonstrates this. How **exactly** do the results differ? We don't need to care about all of the Base36 stuff on top of the issue.

Comment: Does VB.net use 1-based arrays or something like that?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Ew no :D

Comment: Why the ToCharArray? I'm pretty sure string is IEnumerable<char>.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: thank you for pointing out such a common problem on this site. People do like to insist that basic features of commonly-used platforms are broken and that the problem is *surely* on line X, but they won't bother building tests that show that to be the case. It's not even that hard to do. Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Mod` operator:

```
clistarr(input Mod 36)
```

But the actual issue is

```
input /= 36
```

In C#, `/` is integer division when used on two `int`s. In VB.NET, `/` is `Double` on `Integer`s and it uses bankers’ rounding. Change it to integer division:

```
input \= 36
```

Or use `DivMod` properly:

```
input = Math.DivRem(input, 36, remainder)
```

Comment: @aleroot: Try `input \= 36` instead of `input /= 36`. Or just do `input = Math.DivRem(input, 36, remainder)` as you had originally written, since this *is* what `DivRem` is for.

Comment: what is remainder ?